# Send variable value to next view controller when click a table cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, global-variables, didselectrowatindexpath

I have two table view controllers

1. `InvoiceList` view controller
2. `InvoiceShow` view controller

I use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method as bellow to get selected table cell specific value

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     let rowObject = objects[indexPath.row]
     let invoicehash = rowObject["hash_key"]!
}
```

i need to send `invoicehash` value to `InvoiceShow` controller when click the table cell of `InvoiceList`

i tried to use `prepareForSegue` function. but it is not applicable because it will trigger before the `didSelectRawAtIndexPath` function. so when i implemented it, gives the previous click event variable value. not correct one.

Please help me to access `invoiceHash` variable value from `InvoiceShow` controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get the selected cell in `prepareForSegue` method itself.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  let selectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!

  let rowObject = objects[selectedIndexPath.row]
  let invoiceHash = rowObject["hash_key"]!

  let invoiceShowViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! InvoiceShowViewController

  // Set invoiceHash to `InvoiceShowViewController ` here
  invoiceShowViewController.invoiceHash = invoiceHash
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can still use a segue if you want and/or already setup on your storyboard. 
You just need to connect the two view controllers in Interface Builder directly from one to another. 
So, start ctrl-dragging from the controller itself and not from the TableViewCell (take a look at the screenshot)

[image: Ctrl-drag from ViewController to ViewController]

then use the performSegueMethod with the new segue identifier like this:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegueIdentifier", sender: self)
```

and finally, your prepareForSegue method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mySegueIdentifier" {
        let selectedIndex = self.invoiceTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        //if element exist
        if selectedIndex?.row < myDataSourceArray.count {
            let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! InvoiceShowViewController
            let invoice = myDataSourceArray[selectedIndex!.row]
            destination.invoice = invoice
        }
    }
}
```

That's it!