# How to pass an array to a view controller depending on button click?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, uibutton

So I'm creating a quiz app...

App Layout:

View Controller1: **Choose quiz topic**

Sports (UIbutton)

Math (UIButton)

Cars (UIButton)

Animals (UIButton)

***(Depending on which button the user clicks it will take them to another View Controller that lists a few categories that the user can choose from to be quized on)***

ViewController2: **Choose quiz category**

**Category - Animals**

mammals (UIButton)

reptiles (UIButton)

carnivors (UIButton)

fish (UIButton)

**(Now depending on the users choice of category, I want to be able to send the questions through one View Controller, instead of making multiple view controllers of the same view that are specific to each category.)**

Hopefully that makes sense....

I have multiple question banks setup that hold questions specific to category

Here is the model I use:

import Foundation

```
class Questions {
  let questionText : String
  let answer : String
  let option1 : String
  let option2 : String
  let option3 : String
  let option4 : String

  init(text: String, correctAnswer: String, textA: String, textB: String, textC: String, textD: String) {
    questionText = text
    answer = correctAnswer
    option1 = textA
    option2 = textB
    option3 = textC
    option4 = textD
  }
}
```

And here is the QuestionBank.swift file that holds the questions

```
import Foundation

class QuestionBank1 {
  var list = [Questions]()

  init() {

    list.append(item)

    list.append = (Questions(text: "What is the largest animal found on earth?", correctAnswer: "elephant", textA: "tiger", textB: "grey whale", textC: "lion", textD: "elephant" ))   
  }
}
```

So hopefully your still with me, and yes obviously there are more questions in the question bank, but how can I pass certain QuestionBank.swift files through one view controller that handles asking the question and providing 4 multiple choice answers, depending on the category picked by the user on the previous view controller, Does that make sense?

PS I'm new to coding and still trying to get the language right

Comment: You can use callbacks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass on the questions list related to that particular category in the `prepareForSegue` method. In your `Questions` Model you have to add the category attribute.

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33659325/7113671) on how to do this.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  let selectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!

  let selectedCategory = categories[selectedIndexPath.row]
  let categoryQuestions = questions.filter({$0.category == selectedCategory})
  let questionsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! QuestionsViewController
  questionsViewController.questions = questions
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.